# Dynamically adding to the Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

Is it possible to dynamically add to a Localizable.strings file? My app will download new objects and I need to add the translations. If I can somehow add to the Localizable.strings file I can just call `NSLocalizedString`. Is this possible at all? Had a google around for this couldn't find anything that looked too concrete.

Comment: What are these new objects? How are you getting them?

Comment: My app has a custom class "stickers", each sticker has a title, UIImage, bio etc. I will be downloading new ones from Parse.com and then saving them to a dictionary. I can include strings of course with each sticker for the various languages but need some way to access/edit Localizable.strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a language parameter to parse and have it send back just the appropriate language.

Or, you can have it send back a bundle which contains the localisation details, then use `- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName` to extract the details.

Comment: The first solution you mean essentially just make my own method to switch the strings based on what language the phone is set to?

Comment: The second one, does the app need to be restarted for the new bundle to be used though? Was looking in to doing something like this